# Función que me permita restringir que el usuario adquiera más productos de los que hay

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo un pequeño problema.

Mi proyecto cuenta con los formularios "Registro de producto", "Registro de categoría", y además, "Entrada y Salida de productos", estos 2 últimos permiten que el usuario ingrese y pueda sacar dichos productos (Son 2 formularios distintos). Pero la cuestión es que él usuario cuando "saca" un producto, "superior" a la cantidad en bodega, este se guarda en el historial "Movimientos de salida" pero en negativo.

Ejemplo:

1. Tengo 50 lápices azules.
2. Él usuario saca 51.
3. Por ende, me quedan -1 en mi historial "Movimientos de salida".

¿Cómo puedo hacer una especie de validación, para que él usuario no pueda sacar más de la cantidad que tiene ese producto?

Comment: Con un `if` antes de enviar a la BDD.

Comment: Esto involucra tanto a tu backend como a tu frontend, por ejemplo en la interfaz donde elige, debería evaluar cobtra la base de datos para que cuando la cantidad de stock sea por ejemplo `===` a 1 entonces le deshabilite ciertos botones y no pueda elegir mas, por otro lado te recomiendo leer [ask] pues tu pregunta es basada en opiniones y eso generará su cierre

Comment: Solamente es crear una condicion que valide el stock actual y los productos a saca como lo siguiente: `if ( $actual < $sacar ){ echo 'No mas productos' }`

Answer (score 0):

Debes validar tanto tu front-end, back-end y la tabla de base de datos

1. Para el caso del front-end:

Si tienes acceso a la cantidad máxima de productos en tu input agregar max

```
<input type="number" id="pencil" name="pencil" min="1" max="max-value">
```

de esta manera el input validará que no pueda ingresar un valor superior al que tienes

2. Para el back-end con un "if"

   if ($valorEntrada > $maximo) {
   echo "valor ingresado es mayor al permitido";
   }
3. para la base de datos

para mySQL

```
CREATE TABLE movimientos (
    cantidad_columna int(11) unsigned
);
```

para oracle, postgreSQL agregar un constraint

```
create table movimientos(
  cantidad_columna numeric CONSTRAINT positive_cantidad CHECK (cantidad_columna > 0)
);
```

Comment: Se te agradece el aporte, pero te comento que las preguntas amplias y basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, por tanto es mejor no responderlas, además el OP indica en las etiquetas usar mysql por tanto la parte de postgresql y oracle esta demás